# GoogleTV Primetime view

Tags: gridview, google-tv

I have to create application that uses GoogleTV primetime navigation concept.

If you ever see the primetime app on GoogleTV you know what I'm talking about.

There is something that looks like a GridView, but clearly it is not that simple.
There are always visible 3 or 4 rows, and selector is always on center row...
Content scrolls up and down, and selection is always on the same row.

Also in the row there are always up to 5,6 items, and when you try to navigate left or right...content of the selected row scroll horizontally.

So it look that this is nested grid view and scroll view...or even nested vertical and horizontal scroll view...

Do you have any idea what is this view? Or is there some library that provides this kind of view widget?

Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a full blown custom set of views;
This is not a compound view, to my knowledge there are no libraries emulating this.
You will have to implement this yourself.